# How to render CMS content into view in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system

Rails newbie here.

Using Comfortable Mexican Sofa as my CMS.

I have an application where the user show page has its own layout with a sidebar navigation. The sidebar links are generated with

```
<% Comfy::Cms::Site.first.pages.root.children.published.each do |page| %>
<li><%= link_to page.label, page.url(:relative) %></li> 
<% end %>
```

I want the yield for that layout to generate the corresponding content. There must be a super Rails way of accomplishing that, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for `content_for`.

Within your template you can capture parts for later use like this:

```erb
  <% content_for :sidebar do %>
   <% Comfy::Cms::Site.first.pages.root.children.published.each do |page| %>
     <li><%= link_to page.label, page.url(:relative) %></li> 
   <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Within your layout or other template you can use it like this:

```erb
 <%= content_for :sidebar %>
```

Comment: This causes the contents of the sidebar to render in the main content div and not in the sidebar div.

Comment: It depends where you place `<%= content_for :sidebar %>` . You can put it every where.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't good at explaining. The code I had did fine at generating the sidebar. What I want to use content_for for is the content of the pages that the links go to - so that when I click the link, the yield or content_for changes into that links contents.

Comment: Ok, you want to render the content of an cms page. I don't know for sure but maybe `render :cms_page => page.url(:relative)` can to the job. The CMS wiki has a section about "Accessing cms content from the app".